Get Tooltip Text Of Field Using pdf-lib
I am using pdf-lib library to read and manipulate form.
I have created a simple component in nextjs that uploads a pdf file and reads its field. I was successful in getting the field type and field name but was unable to get the field tooltip text, I have provided my code below. Not sure if it's possible with pdf-lib or not because I checked official docs and didn't find to do it
  const handleFileChange = async (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    setSelectedFile(file);

    // Read the uploaded PDF file
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = async (e) => {
      const bytes = e.target.result;

      const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(bytes);
      const form = pdfDoc.getForm();
      const fields = form.getFields();
      fields.forEach((field) => {
        const type = field.constructor.name;
        console.log(field);
        const name = field.getName();

        console.log(`${type}: ${name}`);
      });

      setFieldsWithLabels(fieldsWithLabels);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  };

